# Trying to display different images for my adversarial attack

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

for this code I am  required to implement an FGSM attack against all examples and calculate the success rate. Also, display the original image with the attacked image as well as the predicted class for each image. However, what is being shown on my notebook is the same images of dogs- is there something wrong in my current code?

```
def try_fool(img_path, epsilon):



# Lets's import an image to process. -- copied from above^^
#image_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg', 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg')
image_raw = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
image = tf.image.decode_png(image_raw)
input_image = preprocess(image)
reversed_image = reverse_preprocess(input_image)
preprocessed_img, _ = sess.run([input_image, reversed_image])


img_probs = sess.run(pretrained_model, {input_image_placeholder: preprocessed_img})
top_1 = list(get_imagenet_label(img_probs))[0]

# preturbation ^^ copied from above
perturbations = create_adversarial_pattern(input_image_placeholder, tf.argmax(pretrained_model,1))
adv_x = input_image_placeholder + epsilon*perturbations[0]
adv_x = tf.clip_by_value(adv_x, -1, 1)
rev_image_atcked = reverse_preprocess(adv_x)
_, raw_img_atcked = sess.run([image, rev_image_atcked], {input_image_placeholder: preprocessed_img})

# new image..
img_probs_attacked = sess.run(pretrained_model, {input_image_placeholder: raw_img_atcked})
top_1_attacked = list(get_imagenet_label(img_probs_attacked))[0]

_, raw_adv_img = sess.run([image, reversed_image], {input_image_placeholder: preprocessed_img})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 3))
fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)

#original image
plt.imshow(raw_adv_img[0])
plt.gca().axis('off')
plt.title(top_1)

fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(raw_img_atcked[0])
plt.gca().axis('off')
plt.title(top_1_attacked)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

return top_1[1] != top_1_attacked[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be careful of with Jupyter notebooks is once you run a cell that declares a variable in global scope, that variable will persist as declared until you redeclare the variable, manually delete the variable (not common or necessary), or restart your Jupyter notebook kernel.

My guess is you ran it once with the following not commented out:

```
#image_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file('YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg', 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg')
```

Notice how your other code still makes use of `image_path` (such as `image_raw = tf.io.read_file(image_path)`)

It looks like you want to first indent your code properly to be inside your function definition for `try_fool`, and then change `image_path` to `img_path`. Otherwise, every time you run your notebook you'll be using the two images defined in `image_path`.